# httpd RewriteRule not working as expected

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, awstats

On my server I am running [awstats](http://www.awstats.org/), a script that I can currently access via the following URL:

> https://stats.example.com/bin/awstats.pl/?config=global

I am trying to use rewrite rules such that I can just use

> https://stats.example.com/global

This is what I have defined for a rewrite rule

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bin/awstats.pl/?config=$1 [NC,L]

httpd virtual host

```
# Address
ServerName              stats.example.com

# Rewrite
RewriteRule      ^(.*)$ bin/awstats.pl/?config=$1 [NC,L]

Options                 ExecCGI
AddHandler              cgi-script .cgi .pl
Alias                   /awstatsstuff "/path/to/awstatsstuff/"

<Directory "/path/to/awstatsstuff">
        Options ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The problem is that anything I try and access (besides the index), will give me a 400, and my apache logs show no errors.

Should this rule be working correctly, do I have a different configuration issue? Or am I missing something? Yes, `RewriteEngine` is on.

---

**edit**

Based on Michael Berkowski's comment I determined that is *is* infact an issue with resources also being directed to the pl script, I have since modified and am using the following:

```
RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule             ^/([0-9a-z]+\.[0-9a-z]+\.[0-9a-z]+)$    bin/awstats.pl/?config=$1 [NC,L]
```

I can now load the page again using

> https://stats.example.com/bin/awstats.pl/?config=www.example.com

This means that all resources can be loaded correctly, however

> https://stats.example.com/www.exmaple.com

will return a 400 ( this does not come from the pl script which will return a 200 and error message if the specified config file can not be found, again, no error messages in the logs.

---

**another edit**

In changing `[NC,L]` to `[R=302]`, I am provided with the correct redirect upon request,

```
curl -k "https://stats.example.com/a.b.c"
...
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://stats.example.com/bin/awstats.pl/?config=a.b.c">here</a>.</p>
...
```

Using `[R=403]` proves that the rewrite rule is working as expected

The problem that I am now facing is that when using `[NC,L]`, I am still receiving a `400`, with no errors available in the httpd log.

Comment: Is that your only RewriteRule? My assumption is that other things like image files, favicon.ico, etc are being sent into the `config=` variable, and awstats is choking on that. Is the `config=` parameter limited to a few possible values, or at least to a specific range of characters like all lowercase, a-z only?

Comment: Ahhhhh, that might do it... The config will be a 3 part FQDN, `www.example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect requests for documents other than the index are being mistakenly trapped by the very permissive `(.*)` and sent to `config=` in error. The 400 (bad request) probably then results from awstats tripping over values it cannot handle there.

Two things should take place. First, you need to exclude real existing files and directories from the rewrite, conventionally done with a pair of `RewriteCond`.  Then, instead of the very general `(.*)` matcher, use a matcher more specific to the values that should actually be considered valid for `config=`.

```
# If the requested document is not a known
# file or directory on disk...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=d

# Rewrite patterns matching only the expected
# config= values for awstats
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+)$ bin/awstats.pl?config=$1 [L,NC]
```

Above I have used `[a-z0-9]+\.` to match 3 part FQDN strings as mentioned in the comment thread. That may need additional refinement. To also support the string `"global"` for example, you could expand it to

```
RewriteRule ^(global|[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+)$ bin/awstats.pl?config=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Yeah, the permissive rule is definitely the problem, I have been playing with it trying to get it work since posting. Will try this out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: This was definately a start of my problem, and was the direction I was headed ( you only support single chars ;) `a.b.c`, please see my edit for some more information.

Comment: Yep, should have a `+` at the end of each `[]` group.

Comment: Are you doing the rewrite in .htaccess, or in a `<Directory>` or `<VirtualHost>`?

Comment: So you're still not getting a rewrite. If you test again with the more general `(.*)` instead of the FQDN pattern (keeping the RewriteCond in place) do you get somewhere yet? Your browser could possibly be holding onto an earlier response in cache. That always makes debugging rewrite rules difficult.

Comment: Temporarily add the `[R=302]` flag to see visually in the address bar if the string is being passed to `config=`

Comment: From `curl "https://stats.example.com/a.b.c"` == `The document has moved <a href="https://stats.example.com/awstats.pl/?config=">here</a>` weird... that _half_ worked...

Comment: Whoops, my bad, I was missing `()` in my rewrite rule. So the 302 redirect is correct, what might be causing it to not work with `NC,L`?

Comment: If the 302 works as is, the rewriterule is now correct, there could be something else interfering. Do you have any authentication like HTTP Basic Auth active in this directory?

Comment: No auth, I've posted my entire vhost config.

Comment: I can't continue any further tonight unfortunately. Looks like the RewriteRule component is working in and of itself, but awstats may dislike the path munging that has taken place. I can't tell if rewriting is supported in this manner for awstats.

Comment: I guess I can live with the 302 for now, I appreciate the help - you solved the RewriteRule like I was asking for, now to figure out whats going on with AWStats. Cheers :)